# Как написать клиент для чужого сайта?

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

возник такой вопрос: возможно ли написать приложение под android, которое будет работать со сторонним сайтом? Интересующая на нем страничка имеет простое содержание:
[image: Содержание странички]

То есть ввод показаний со счетчиков.
Каким образом я могу привязать все эти кнопки и вылезающие текстовые поля к своим, которые будут находится в приложении? Сразу извинюсь за неверную терминологию и прочее.

Comment: Сайт должен иметь api и вы должны используя его взаимодействовать с сайтом.

Comment: Должен, но не обязан... Если есть открытое API, то всё просто - читаем доку к нему и пишем запросы. Если нет API, то всё гораздо веселее - нужно брать библиотеку `jsoup`, скачивать нужные страницы сайта и вытаскивать интересующую информацию. Потом подсматривать как из браузера отправляются данные на сервер и повторять эти запросы в коде. Есть ещё вариант простой - тупо грузить сайт в `WebView`, но тогда грош цена такому приложению.

Comment: @woesss, иногда и `Jsoup` будет недостаточно, у нужен будет `Selenium`) Ну и в итоге приложение это можно будет только вручную на телефоны ставить, ибо гугл такое будет у себя в GooglePlay банить, если, конечно, автор приложения не получил официальных бумаг от владельцев сайта на право информацию с него использовать или если не спрятал все запросы к сайту за собственным API.